# C++ STL container for template base class

Tags: c++, templates, base-class

I am attempting to store objects derived from a templated base class in an STL map.  However, attempting to insert derived (or indeed base) objects returns:

```
C2440 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'CBase<T> ' to 'CBase<T>'
```

I understand using derived classes is one accepted way of making an STL container heterogenous (http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/containers.html#faq-34.4).  I would like to know if it is possible to use a template in this context.  It would be very convenient as I could have a single declaration of a range of containers in the base class that are instantiated for my various types at compile time, instead of duplicate declarations in non-templated derived classes.

My code is as follows:

```
//Header
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class CBase
{
    public:
        CBase::CBase() {};
        virtual CBase::~CBase() {};
        vector<pair<int, T> > RetrieveVect() { return vect; };

    private:
        vector<pair<int, T> > vect;
};

class CDerivedString : public CBase<string>
{
    ...
};

class CDerivedInt : public CBase<int>
{
    ...
};

//cpp
int main(void)
{
    //Map specialised for pointer to base class
    map<string, CBase<class T>* > m_myMap;

    string s = "key";

    //Create and insert object (base class)
    CBase<int> *dataInt = new CBase();
    //The following results in error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'CBase<T> ' to 'CBase<T>
    m_myMap.insert(std::make_pair(s, dataInt));

    //Create and insert object (derived class)
    CBase<int> *dataBase = new CBase<int>();
    //The following results in error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'CBase<T> ' to 'CBase<T>
    m_myMap.insert(pair<string, CBase<class T>* >(s, static_cast<CBase*>(dataInt)));
}
```

I've tried doing a dynamic_cast on the derived class pointer to cast it to a base pointer type but this didn't work either:

```
//error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'CBase<T> *' to 'CBase<T> *'
m_myMap.insert(pair<string, CBase<class T>* >(s, static_cast<CBase<class T>*>(dataInt)));
```

Comment: Do you mean "class CDerivedString : public CBase<string>"?

Comment: I've edited to show the angle brackets which got hidden, but it seems the error message is still missing something (note the space) from what it originally said.

Comment: Do you mean "class CDerivedString : public CBase<string>"? Yes - I've corrected the code above which came from a messy cut and paste operation.  I don't think anything's missing now.

Comment: Thanks very much for the replies.  I will try Keith's suggestion of defining a fully generic base, and using a smart ptr map from Boost to contain pointers to the base class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following line:

```
map<string, CBase<class T>* > m_myMap;
```

almost certainly does not mean what you think it does. This is equivalent to:

```
map<string, CBase<T>* > m_myMap;
```

That is: 'T' is a concrete class, not a template parameter. There is of course no relationship between the classes:

```
CBase<int>
```

and

```
CBase<T>
```

Hence the error message - you have never defined (or intended to) the concrete class 'T'. Take SCFrench's comment re using the correct base and then use that in the map<>:

```
map<string, CBase<int>* > m_myIntMap;
```

will allow you to store the concrete CDerivedInt* objects. If you want to store any object, define a fully generic base:

```
 class CBaseAbc 
     { 
        virtual ~CBaseAbc() = 0;
     };
 template<class T>
 class CBase : public CBaseAbc 
    {
     // etc.
    };

map<string, CBaseAbc* > m_myAnthingMap;
```

Comment: Though you don't show it, this is likely to lead to raw pointers which "own" their resources being stored in a map, and that will lead to leaks.  Use a smart container (such as from Boost) or a container of smart pointers.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  This is the sort of approach I had in mind.  When you say the pointers "own" their resources, I thought in turn the map "owns" the pointers so when destructed, so long as the destructors in the pointed-to objects are all virtual, nothing should get leaked.  If I use a smart container (such as boost::ptr_map) instead of std::map, do you think the approach above should work?  Thanks again!

Comment: 'the map "owns" the pointers '; this is literally true, but only the storage used for the pointers is erased, not the object pointed to. So, yes, use boost::ptr_map or such if you wish the map to own the objects pointed to. See other answers for details.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Boost's Pointer Containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html), which exactly provide a "map specialised for pointer to base class" that you tried:

```
// Use whichever is appropriate since you've written CBase as a template:
boost::ptr_map<string, CBase<int> > m_myMap;
boost::ptr_map<string, CBase<string> > m_myMap;

// If CBase were instead not a template base class:
boost::ptr_map<string, CBase> m_myMap;
```

Since you use T in CBase's interface, it appears you want to keep CBase as a template, but be aware that in that case, there is no common base class between classes derived from CBase<int> and CBase<string>, as these are two different types, and you cannot store classes derived from either in a single container.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a base class to store in the `std::map`; that needs to either be a non-templated class or a specific instance of a template.  It is not possible to store "any instance of `CBase`" unless there is a common base class for all instances.  You might also want to consider using `boost::shared_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` to automatically manage the lifetimes of your objects.